# acceder al HttpContext.Cache desde Javscript

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

En mi aplicación inicializo un HttpContext.Cache con una clave y agrego información, pero hasta ahora sólo he logrado acceder a esa información de lado servidor (es decir desde archivos CS)

```
FilterRecote restees = new FilterRecote();
 if (HttpContext.Current.Cache["filters"] == null)
        {

            if (rest.Count > 0)
            {
                List<string> destino = (from item in rest group item.nombredestino by item.nombredestino into x select x.Key).ToList();

                List<int> categoria = (from item in rest group item.categoria by item.categoria into c select c.Key).ToList();

                List<string> mes = (from item in rest group item.FechaLlegada by item.FechaLlegada into m select m.Key).ToList();

                int maxNoches = rest.Max(p => p.Num_noches);

                int minPreci = Convert.ToInt32(rest.Min(p => p.Precio));

                int maxPreci = Convert.ToInt32(rest.Max(p => p.Precio)); ;

                FilterRecote filtros = new FilterRecote()
                {
                    Destino = destino,
                    Categoria = categoria,
                    Mes = mes,
                    minPrecio = minPreci,
                    maxPrecio = maxPreci,
                    maxNoche = maxNoches
                };

                HttpContext.Current.Cache.Insert("filters", filtros, null, DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(15), System.Web.Caching.Cache.NoSlidingExpiration);
            }
            else
                isredirect = true;
        }
        else
            restees = (FilterRecote)HttpContext.Current.Cache["filters"];
```

pero me gustaria acceder a esa información de lado cliente, si fuera posible.

O es que existe alguna otra forma de guardar en cache lado servidor y poder consultar de lado cliente, como alternativa a http.cache

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No creo que exista lo que indicas ni tampoco parece buena idea que exista algo así. Tal y como comentas una cosa es el servidor y otra el cliente. 
Lo que se ejecuta dentro del servidor no puede verlo el cliente (por seguridad entre otras cosas) y el cliente solo debería ver lo que le responde el servidor. Incluso Redis está pensado para el node en el servidor y no para el cliente.

En este caso si quieres utilizar esos datos lo que tienes es que crear un método en tu API o controlador que devuelva esos datos con JSON. De esta manera desde el cliente puedes pedir esos datos al servidor y utilizarlos en tu código javascript.

Uno puede estar tentado a hacer un método que le pases la clave y el servidor te devuleva el valor de esa clave en la caché del servidor. Pero tampoco sería buena idea ya que el tiempo de hacer la petición al servidor y procesar la respuesta haría que todo fuese más lento.

Si los datos que necesitas son maestros que no van a cambiar, yo los cargaría con javascript todos juntos para utilizarlos en la parte cliente. Si son datos que pueden cambiar mucho, yo solo confiaría en los datos devueltos por el servidor en el momento de procesar la petición. Y si necesitase algún mecanismo para actualizar los datos en el javascript según lo que pasase en el servidor, intentaría mover mi solución a algo del tipo reactivo.

Los mestros se pueden obtener del servidor de muchas formas, por ejemplo:

```
public JsonResult ObtenerMaestros()
{
    var datos = new
    {
      Paises = PaisDao.FindAll(),
      Monedas = MonedasDao.FindAll(),
    };

    return Json(datos);
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por tus comentarios, sin duda una buena explicación, ahora me has enseñado nuevos conceptos sobre esto de lado cliente y lado servidor